# Android Voice Recognition Call Adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, voice-recognition

i would be really grateful if someone is aware of a way to resolve this.

My issue is I need to get voice recognition to start as a call is detected through an android app so a person  can accept,reject call or dial numbers by voice only.

1.Currently the task is activated after the call has ended.i.e. Voice recognition starts after the call but i need it to appear during the call coming in to assert a command such as "Answer Phone" to accept the call.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call
            VoiceRecognitionActivity.speak(null);

            // get the phone number
            String incomingNumber = intent
                    .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" + incomingNumber,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
            Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}

 <activity
            android:name="com.white.rabbit.MyCallReceiver"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```